# can't get json from google spreadsheet?

Tags: php, json, spreadsheet

i was getting json from spreadsheet till yesterday and suddenly its returning null. I am not getting json from particular spreadsheet file however if i make a new one and do exactly the same, its returning. again after 2-3 days its not working. what's the reason?

this is my code

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
 
// Set your CSV feed

$feed = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/140EWUqZ6NF4q9NqJxegxn1Ulb0Una2i5QU6lBHCtuZ8/export?format=csv&id=140EWUqZ6NF4q9NqJxegxn1Ulb0Una2i5QU6lBHCtuZ8&gid=0';
// Arrays we'll use later
$keys = array();
$newArray = array();
 
function csvToArray($file){
$ch = curl_init();  

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET' );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$lines = preg_split('/\r/', $output);

$array = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
}
return $array;
}

$data=csvToArray($feed);
$count = count($data) - 1;
 
//Use first row for names  
$labels = array_shift($data);  
 
foreach ($labels as $label) {
  $keys[] = $label;
}
 
// Add Ids, just in case we want them later
/*$keys[] = 'id';
 
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
 $data[$i][] = $i;
}
 */
// Bring it all together
for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++) {
  $d = array_combine($keys, $data[$j]);
  $newArray[$j] = $d;
}

// Print it out as JSON
$newstring= json_encode($newArray);
$json = html_entity_decode($newstring);
echo  $json;
 
?>
```

however same code to another spreadsheet works well though

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
 
// Set your CSV feed
 $feed = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N3Lie4UJg9EcQhXVLDez36H1jypHHC65AB2zqd5Y90E/export?format=csv&id=1N3Lie4UJg9EcQhXVLDez36H1jypHHC65AB2zqd5Y90E&gid=1401215638'; 
// Arrays we'll use later
$keys = array();
$newArray = array();

function csvToArray($file){
$ch = curl_init();  

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET' );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);



//separate each line

$lines = preg_split('/\r/', $output);

//$lines = explode(',', $skuList,4000);

$array = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
   
}
return $array;
}

$data=csvToArray($feed);
$count = count($data) - 1;
 
//Use first row for names  
$labels = array_shift($data);  



foreach ($labels as $label) {
  $keys[] = $label;
}
// Add Ids, just in case we want them later
/*$keys[] = 'id';
 
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
 $data[$i][] = $i;
}
 */
// Bring it all together
for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++) {
  //  $keys = array('map','registrar','address','company','price','aa','bb');
  $d = array_combine($keys, $data[$j]);
  $newArray[$j] = $d;
  
}
 
// Print it out as JSON
echo json_encode($newArray);

?>
```

so what is the problem? pls help..

Answer (score 1):

You should add a parameter for curl
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`

so your code will be:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

// Set your CSV feed

$feed = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/140EWUqZ6NF4q9NqJxegxn1Ulb0Una2i5QU6lBHCtuZ8/export?format=csv&id=140EWUqZ6NF4q9NqJxegxn1Ulb0Una2i5QU6lBHCtuZ8&gid=0';
// Arrays we'll use later
$keys = array();
$newArray = array();

function csvToArray($file){
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET' );
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);



    $lines = preg_split('/\r/', $output);

    $array = array();
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
    }
    return $array;
}

$data=csvToArray($feed);
$count = count($data) - 1;

//Use first row for names
$labels = array_shift($data);

foreach ($labels as $label) {
    $keys[] = $label;
}

// Add Ids, just in case we want them later
/*$keys[] = 'id';

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
 $data[$i][] = $i;
}
 */
// Bring it all together
for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++) {
    $d = array_combine($keys, $data[$j]);
    $newArray[$j] = $d;
}

// Print it out as JSON
$newstring= json_encode($newArray);
$json = html_entity_decode($newstring);
echo  $json;
```